# How do i use variable in array index?

Tags: php

I've got a number of individual items. Currently, I go through them  individually but i would like to loop through them. If these were number indexes, I would have no problem there. But since these are names- it's  more of a challenge. Couldn't find anything, but i may be looking for a wrong thing (are these really array indexes)?

Currently, I check and output them in the following way.

```
                if ($term_meta['term_1']) { echo '"'.$term_meta['term_1'].'",'; } 
                if ($term_meta['term_2']) { echo '"'.$term_meta['term_2'].'",'; } 
                if ($term_meta['term_3']) { echo '"'.$term_meta['term_3'].'",'; } 
                if ($term_meta['term_4']) { echo '"'.$term_meta['term_4'].'",'; } 
                if ($term_meta['term_5']) { echo '"'.$term_meta['term_5'].'",'; } 
                if ($term_meta['term_6']) { echo '"'.$term_meta['term_6'].'",'; } 
                if ($term_meta['term_7']) { echo '"'.$term_meta['term_7'].'",'; } 
                if ($term_meta['term_8']) { echo '"'.$term_meta['term_8'].'",'; }
```

And I would like to achieve similar result with loop looking somewhat like this. But I can't make these variables work.

```
for ($terms_num = 1; $terms_num<=8; $terms_num++) {
    if ($term_meta['term_'+$terms_num]) { echo '"'.$term_meta['term_'+$terms_num].'",';}
}
```

Comment: you use `.` to concatenate, `+` will try to add the two values mathematically

Comment: like this? $term_meta['term_'.$terms_num]

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php you concatenate with '.'
also you cant check if the key is in the array like this instead use array_key_exists (or something similar I dont claim to know all the php libs)

```
for ($terms_num = 1; $terms_num<=8; $terms_num++) {
    if (array_key_exists('term_'.$terms_num,$term_meta) { 
        echo '"'.$term_meta['term_'.$terms_num].'",';
    }
}
```

Comment: which to be honest you actually used in the echo line oO

Comment: simple enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use array_filter and implode.
Array_filter will remove any null or empty values, and implode will build a string from your array.

```
echo '"' . implode('","', array_filter($term_meta)) . '"';
```

See example here:
https://3v4l.org/vCrMM

Looping as the other answer will create a trailing comma that is (probably) unwanted.
Using implode will not create any trailing commas.